# when is G inside interior of A?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A$ and $G$ are subsets of the topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ and let $\mathcal N_a$ denote the set of all neighborhoods of $a\in X$. Are these equivalent:

1. $(\forall y \in G)(\exists U\in \mathcal N_y): U\subseteq A$.
2. $(\forall y \in G)(\exists U\in \mathcal N_y): U\subseteq A^o$.

where $A^o$ is the interior of $A$.

Comment: what is the relation between A and G?

Comment: **Hint:** $U \subset A$ implies $(U \cap A)^o = U^o = U = U \cap A$.

Comment: How do you define neighborhood?

Comment: @JacobSchlather: any set containing an open set containing $a$  is considered a neighborhood of $a$ in most books.

Comment: Well, then my book must have been not one of those "most books". Thanks to Jacob for fixing this issue.

Comment: @dtldarek: your book has defined open-neighborhoods as a neighborhoods: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly if (2) holds then (1) holds. Suppose that (1) holds and let $y \in G$ then  we have some neighborhood $U$ of $y$ such that $U \subset A$. Let $V=U^o$, note that $y \in V$. Now apply the hint dtldarek provided.

Answer (score 2):

I think basically it's clear:

(1) $\iff G\subseteq A^o $

(2) $\iff G\subseteq (A^o)^o $

while

$A^o=(A^o)^o$